# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.type.FloatType cannot be cast to org.hibernate.type.VersionType

Tags: java, hibernate, version, classcastexception

I have a problem to configure Hibernate in NetBeans 8.1 .

I have created :

- HibernateUtil.java

and hibernateConfig :

- hibernate.cfg.xml
- hibernate.reveng.xml

and model.beans / mapping files :

- categorie.hbm.xml
- categorie.java
- login.hbm.xml
- login.java
- software.hbm.xml
- software.java

[image]

Comment: post some code along with stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

from the error mentioned it says,

ClassCastExcpetion : `floattype` cannot be cast to `version` type

please change field datatype mapped to @version from `float` to `int`.

Comment: i have a float type in my database mySQL .

Comment: version can`t be of float type

Comment: So I have to change float to int
it will not cause problems ?

Comment: I changed  float type to java.lang.Integer but i have some error :
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer